# Excel - Get data from a web API with query parameters that change by cell

Tags: excel, vba, api, excel-formula

I have a web API (that I control) that does a specific calculation based on the URL parameters.
I want to be able to pull information using that API based on information in every row of my Excel file.

For example, imagine my API sums up two numbers passed in the query:

`www.api.com/?num1=2&num2=3`

My Excel file has two columns - num1 and num2 and I want the result column to contain the results of the query.

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      num1           |     num2         |     result       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        2            |      3           |        5         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

How can I achieve this in Excel?
In Google sheets I would just use =IMPORTDATA() and build the url based on cell values.

I tried using Web Data Import, but seems like it's designed to get entire datasets and I couldn't figure
out a way to change the query parameters dynamically.

I prefer a solution that's "native" to Excel, if possible, without writing VBA or creating addons.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: So basically you are pulling in a string containing these variables? Would it always have the construct `"www.api.com/?num1=2&num2=3"` ?

Comment: The url always has the same structure and the same variables. Their value needs to change based on the cell value.

Comment: Looks like you need to look at `WEBSERVICE()` and `FILTERXML` functions.

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks!